# when testing api from test.py getting Doesnot exist , matching query does not exists and while testing same api from postman it runs perfectly

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

test.py

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
import json
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from ..serializers import *
from ..models import *

client = Client()


class Parking(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.park_data = {
            "car_id": 36,
            "slot_id": 327
        }
    def test_unpark(self):
        unpark_data = {
            "car_id": 33,
        }
        response = client.post(
            reverse('unpark'),
            data=json.dumps(unpark_data),
            content_type='application/json'
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@csrf_exempt
def unpark_my_car(request):
    car_id = request.data.get('car_id')
    if car_id is not None:
        car_object = Car.objects.get(id=car_id)
        if car_object:
            slot_id = car_object.slot_id
            slot_object = Slot.objects.get(id=slot_id)
            slot_object.parked_car = None
            slot_object.status = "VACANT"
            slot_object.save()
            park_id = car_object.park_id
            park_object = ParkingArea.objects.get(id=park_id)
            valet_id = car_object.valet_assigned_id
            valet_object = Valet.objects.get(id=valet_id)
            valet_object.is_Currently_Parking = False
            valet_object.vehicle_assigned = None
            valet_object.save()
            park_object.filled_parking_slots = park_object.filled_parking_slots - 1
            if park_object.status == "FULL":
                park_object.status = "VACANT"
                notify_owner_car_is_unparked.delay(park_object.id)
                notify_airport_security_car_is_unparked.delay(park_object.id)
            park_object.save()
            car_object.is_parked = False
            car_object.slot_id = None
            car_object.park_id = None
            car_object.valet_assigned_id = None
            car_object.save()
            return Response(status=HTTP_200_OK, data={'msg': 'Car Un-parked'})
        else:
            return Response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data={"msg": 'Car not Found'})

    else:
        return Response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data={"msg": "car id provided is null"})
```

console

```
Saurabh@DESKTOP-Q8U2ADF MINGW64 /f/Fellowship/ParkingLot/Parking_Lot (UC-9)
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
........E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_unpark (ParkingSystemApp.tests_parking.test_views.Parking)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\Parking_Lot\ParkingSystemApp\tests_parking\test_views.py", line 34, in test_unpark
    content_type='application/json'
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 748, in post
    response = super().post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, secure=secure, **extra)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 405, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 470, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 716, in request
    self.check_exception(response)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 577, in check_exception
    raise exc_value
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\Parking_Lot\ParkingSystemApp\views.py", line 368, in unpark_my_car
    car_object = Car.objects.get(id=car_id)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 431, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
ParkingSystemApp.models.Car.DoesNotExist: Car matching query does not exist.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 9 tests in 0.305s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

Saurabh@DESKTOP-Q8U2ADF MINGW64 /f/Fellowship/ParkingLot/Parking_Lot (UC-9)
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
........E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_unpark (ParkingSystemApp.tests_parking.test_views.Parking)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\Parking_Lot\ParkingSystemApp\tests_parking\test_views.py", line 34, in test_unpark
    content_type='application/json'
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 748, in post
    response = super().post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, secure=secure, **extra)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 405, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 470, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 716, in request
    self.check_exception(response)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 577, in check_exception
    raise exc_value
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\Parking_Lot\ParkingSystemApp\views.py", line 368, in unpark_my_car
    car_object = Car.objects.get(id=car_id)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 431, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
ParkingSystemApp.models.Car.DoesNotExist: Car matching query does not exist.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 9 tests in 0.473s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

Saurabh@DESKTOP-Q8U2ADF MINGW64 /f/Fellowship/ParkingLot/Parking_Lot (UC-9)
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
........E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_unpark (ParkingSystemApp.tests_parking.test_views.Parking)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\Parking_Lot\ParkingSystemApp\tests_parking\test_views.py", line 34, in test_unpark
    content_type='application/json'
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 748, in post
    response = super().post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, secure=secure, **extra)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 405, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 470, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 716, in request
    self.check_exception(response)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 577, in check_exception
    raise exc_value
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\Parking_Lot\ParkingSystemApp\views.py", line 368, in unpark_my_car
    car_object = Car.objects.get(id=car_id)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 431, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
ParkingSystemApp.models.Car.DoesNotExist: Car matching query does not exist.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 9 tests in 0.363s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

Saurabh@DESKTOP-Q8U2ADF MINGW64 /f/Fellowship/ParkingLot/Parking_Lot (UC-9)
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
........E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_unpark (ParkingSystemApp.tests_parking.test_views.Parking)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\Parking_Lot\ParkingSystemApp\tests_parking\test_views.py", line 33, in test_unpark
    data=json.dumps(unpark_data),
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 748, in post
    response = super().post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, secure=secure, **extra)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 402, in post
    post_data = self._encode_data(data, content_type)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 361, in _encode_data
    return encode_multipart(BOUNDARY, data)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 242, in encode_multipart
    for (key, value) in data.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 9 tests in 0.287s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

Saurabh@DESKTOP-Q8U2ADF MINGW64 /f/Fellowship/ParkingLot/Parking_Lot (UC-9)
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
........E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_unpark (ParkingSystemApp.tests_parking.test_views.Parking)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\Parking_Lot\ParkingSystemApp\tests_parking\test_views.py", line 34, in test_unpark
    content_type='application/json'
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 748, in post
    response = super().post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, secure=secure, **extra)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 405, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 470, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 716, in request
    self.check_exception(response)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 577, in check_exception
    raise exc_value
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\Parking_Lot\ParkingSystemApp\views.py", line 368, in unpark_my_car
    car_object = Car.objects.get(id=car_id)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 431, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
ParkingSystemApp.models.Car.DoesNotExist: Car matching query does not exist.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 9 tests in 0.450s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

Saurabh@DESKTOP-Q8U2ADF MINGW64 /f/Fellowship/ParkingLot/Parking_Lot (UC-9)
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
........E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_unpark (ParkingSystemApp.tests_parking.test_views.Parking)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\Parking_Lot\ParkingSystemApp\tests_parking\test_views.py", line 34, in test_unpark
    content_type='application/json'
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 748, in post
    response = super().post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, secure=secure, **extra)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 405, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 470, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 716, in request
    self.check_exception(response)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 577, in check_exception
    raise exc_value
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\Parking_Lot\ParkingSystemApp\views.py", line 368, in unpark_my_car
    car_object = Car.objects.get(id=car_id)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Fellowship\ParkingLot\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 431, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
ParkingSystemApp.models.Car.DoesNotExist: Car matching query does not exist.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 9 tests in 1.121s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

while testing from test.py it gives me the above error but when I hit the same API using postman it runs fine.
I am new to django and coding itself help out . i do have data matching the same query it does exists still it is giving error .
i can see the data in the database and also via jango-rest API view and admin panel too.

Comment: are you setting some headers in postman by any chance or is the data supposed to be None for that particular id

Comment: You did not create data for your test case

Comment: from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
comment = get_object_or_404(Car, pk=comment_id)
Or i think the other mistake that you have made is "request.data.get('car_id')" instead of request it should be Car so that it knows which model it has to look and next in get method if you want a particular column then you chANGE your code like this Car.objects.values('car_id')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add sample data in `setUp` method and use them in test methods. Add the sample data like following.

```
class Parking(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.car = Car.objects.create(...)
        self.park_data = {
            "car_id": 36,
            "slot_id": 327
        }
    def test_unpark(self):
        unpark_data = {
            "car_id": self.car.id,
        }
        response = client.post(
            reverse('unpark'),
            data=json.dumps(unpark_data),
            content_type='application/json'
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Notice I have reference `car` in `unpark_data` of `test_unpark`.

Comment: this answer led me to know that I will have to create all the data  I am looking for while testing, cuz it somehow doesn't have access to the already existing database.

Comment: @ProgrammerSaurav, That's correct. It will create a new test database and run the test on it keeping the original database intact.